# React router dom problen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I tried to create a protected route and I created a component like this

```
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {userSelect} from "../../Redux/userSlice";
import {Navigate} from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoute = ({children}) => {
    const currentUser = useSelector(userSelect);
    if (currentUser.user) {
        return children;
    }
    return <Navigate to="/login"/>;
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

but the problem is Navigate not import from react-router-dom just check docs of router-dom and they recommend and use Navigate for the protected route but it isn't working correctly
the main problem is Navigate not import from router-dom
for me, my route-dom version is 6.3.0
does anybody know why this has happened and how to solve this import problem ı try to re-install my node_modules files but still not working

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `useNavigate` instead

```js
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {userSelect} from "../../Redux/userSlice";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoute = ({children}) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const currentUser = useSelector(userSelect);
    if (currentUser.user) {
        return children;
    }
    navigate('/login');
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Comment: its wierd but also not import useNavigate hooks to but all of my routes and link active also useHistory hooks is active but Navigate and useNavigate not import from react-router-dom Thank you React-router-dom for you broke working system the new one absolutly much quicker and usefull :)

Comment: one wierd things to when ı use Webstrom the Navigation not import but on vsCode it work perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't *actually* have `react-router-dom@6` ***installed*** for your project.

You can check the installed version by running `npm list` react-router-dom` from the project directory.

- If the `package.json` file entry for `react-router-dom` is correct then you may just have forgotten to run `npm install` to install the dependencies.

  Run `npm i` to install the project's dependencies.
- If the `package.json` specifies a different version of `react-router-dom` then you'll need to uninstall that version and install v6.

  1. Uninstall current version, and also any version of `react-router` and `history` (*to remove any compatibility issues since v6 uses `history@5`*)

     `npm uninstall -s react-router react-router-dom history`
  2. Install `react-router-dom` v6

     `npm install -s react-router-dom@6`